# How to handle exceptions thrown in react-router child routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, exception, react-router

I'm having an issue with exception handling with `react-router@3.0.0`

My router is attached like this:

```
try {
  ReactDOM.render(<Router history={appHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Wrapper}>
      <Route path='bad' component={BadComponent}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>, domElement);
} catch(ex) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Exception ex={ex}/>, domElement);
}
```

My issue is that if `Wrapper` throws a render exception we end up in the catch block. Great!

If `Wrapper` works fine, but `BadComponent` throws a render exception we do not. Boo!

If we reach this point, then the router completely stops working and we can't navigate to any known good routes.

The react-router API doesn't mention error handling, so I'm a little stuck.

**Is there a way of getting the exception back to the top layer so it can fail gracefully?**

Comment: I don' think there's a way to do this. But I'm wondering... why do you want to catch render exceptions? Why not just debug the component?

Comment: It's more about the user experience if I've made a typo than a development aid.Catching exceptions in components and breaking the whole render tree seems really brittle and unlike other React libraries I've used. Surely, the router should log and throw?

Comment: I'm quite sure that what you're asking isn't possible, unless you wrap every single component in a try catch. Again though, you should be testing your components before pushing your build to your live environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably too late to answer, and you might have found a solution or even not using this code anymore.

In case you haven't found out yet, check the error boundaries that react offers https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html